# PHP 7 - Exception does not get logged in error_log. error_log not geterated at all

Tags: php, exception, php-7, error-reporting, error-log

Following PHP code is run with PHP7:

```
<?php

ini_set('log_errors',1);

error_reporting(0);

throw new Exception('some exception here');

?>
```

Exception is thrown, but not 'catch'-ed.

Why the '**error_log**' file is not generated? Does **error_reporting(0)** suppress exceptions too?

Removing the '**error_reporting(0)**' produces the error_log file, as expected.

How can I log uncaught exceptions only in error_log but suppress other errors with error_reporting(0)?

Answer (score 0):

error_reporting(0) is turning off the error reporting. You are likely confusing it with display_errors which outputs them to the pipe.

See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php for a list of various parameters that can adjust how the logging works.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

add these lines and remove

error_reporting(0);

Comment: display_errors is used to output them to the stdout pipe. If all he wants is output to error_log, he shouldn't need display_errors.